# If $u(P)=1$ , $u(Q)=1/2$ , $u(R)=1/2$. Then find $u(S)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let , $PQRS$ be a rectangle in the first quadrant whose adjacent sides $PQ$ and $QR$ have slopes $1$ and $-1$ respectively.  If $u(x,t)$ is a solution of $\displaystyle \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}-\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}=0$ and $u(P)=1$ , $u(Q)=1/2$ , $u(R)=1/2$. Then find $u(S)$.

I can solve the wave equation. But how I use the rectangle and slopes ?

Please help anyone.

Comment: "I can solve the wave equation." Good, show this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}$ be a 1-dimensional wave equation.

We know that $u(x,t) = F(x-ct)+G(x+ct)$, F,G are arbitrary functions.
Let PQRS be a parallelogram with adjacent sides of slopes $\frac{1}{c}$ and $-\frac{1}{c}$.
Let us fix the coordinates of $P$ to be $P(\xi ,\tau)$.
Let us assume that the side PQ lies
along the family of characteristics: $x−ct = constant$.
Thus the point Q lies on the line $x−ct = \xi − c\tau$. Hence we can find coordinates of Q as $\displaystyle Q\left(\xi+s, \tau+\frac{s}{c}\right)$ for some $s>0$. Since S must lie on a line belonging to the family
of characteristics: $x + c t = constant$, it must lie on the line $x + c t = \xi + c\tau$. Thus the coordinates S are of the form $S(\xi−r,\tau+rc)$ for some $r>0$. Now the coordinates of R can be find easily as $R(\xi-r+s, \tau+\frac{r+s}{c})$.

Now we can varify that  $u(P)+u(R) = u(Q)+u(S)$.

In your question, $c=1$ and slopes of adjacent side of rectangles are 1, -1. clearly PR and QS are diagonals of rectangle.
Just apply above result: $u(S)= u(P) + u(R) - u(Q)$

So, $u(S)=1$